# How to deploy static web app to custom folder in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, url-rewriting, intellij-14

In my static web app if I open `index.html` from IntelliJ IDEA, the project is served from

> http://localhost:port/{project-name}/{folder-name}/index.html

Is it possible to configure this path to something like this?

> http://localhost:port/{custom-folder}/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add Maven dependency below or add urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar directly into your WEB-INF/lib directory.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**2.** Add the following to your `WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**3.** Add `urlrewrite.xml` into your `WEB-INF` directory. (`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` for Maven users)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>

    <rule>
       <from>/{custom-folder}/index.html</from>
       <to type="redirect">/{project-name}/{folder-name}/index.html</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

**4.** Restart, redeploy application

You can visit `http://127.0.0.1:8080/rewrite-status` (or whatever the address of your local webapp and context) to see output (note: this page is only viewable from localhost).

Try `http://localhost:port/{project-name}/{folder-name}/index.html`

Reference: http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html

Comment: hmm , i don't use maven ,i want to configure default webserver  comes from Intellij Idea

Comment: What is your webserver and its version, your programming language? ( I guess it is Java, but if you use IntelliJ IDEA, it may be Scala or Groovy)

Comment: i am talking about built in webserver from Intellij , my web app is static(html,javascript,css)

Comment: When you test on built-in webserver, You still must deploy web content to a real webserver, then we usually using URL_Rewrite technical to do what you want. For testing static content like html, css, I think you do not need rewrite URL. With Apache httpd webserver, create virtual host like this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html . This is maybe what you are talking about: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/php-built-in-web-server.html

Comment: thanks dude thats what i am talking about , do you know what exactly i have to change in Intellij Idea context !